# How do I pass R xyplot a list of y variables?

Tags: r

I am using `xyplot` with inputs `Y1 + Y2 ~ X`.
I would like to pass `Y1 + Y2` as a list, rather than two explicit variables.
That way, I can write a generic `xyplot` function and pass it different values for a series of Ys.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One strategy is to first paste together a character string representation of the formula, and then convert it to an object of class`"formula"`, using `as.formula()`. Here's an example using the `mtcars` dataframe that ships with base R.

```
Y <- c("mpg", "cyl")
f <- as.formula(paste(paste(Y, collapse=" + "), " ~ disp"))
lattice::xyplot(f, data = mtcars)
```